# Limit access to azure logic app api connectors

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-logic-app-standard

I want to set up logic app, which is going to monitor rss feed and create task in azure devops based on data from feed and some conditions. That's the easy part. I want to make this set up more or less secure and want to prevent API connector reuse. So, when I login to Azure DevOps using logic app using connector, API Connection is being created and I can reuse it with any other logic app. How do I prevent this this reuse behaviour? Is it possible to limit connector use somehow, so it can be used with 1 logic app only? The resource group is in subscription which can be accessed by some users already, so limitng access to resource group with logic app is not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to make the API connection restricted to only one logic app. The other possible way would be if you have different user having access to different resource groups, one per user, and set RBAC so only the user have access to it and they are not reusing it. But still that user can also reuse the connection if they want

Comment: Maybe I can achieve some kind of re-use block using deny assignments? For instance: create deny assignment on RG with logic app. This assignment is going to deny any access to the RG and its resources except 1 admin which is supposed to have access.

Comment: UPD. No luck with deny assignments, also tried configuring custom policy, but it failed since logicapp does not have a parameter for resource group.